# Simple URL Rewrite

Tags: asp.net, web-config, url-rewriting

Using http://www.urlrewriting.net/

I want /File1.aspx to be /File1

Ive been trying like this:

```
<add name="Rule1"
     virtualUrl="~/File1"
     desinationUrl="~/File1.aspx"
     rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
     ignoreCase="true"
 />
```

How do i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the URL Rewrite module in IIS7 instead of Umbracos built in module.
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Answer (score 0):

Key issue there is the fact that you are no longer using .aspx and thus IIS isn't letting asp.net process your request. You need to configure IIS to let these requests go through asp.net.

That varies per IIS version, and its harder in [IIS 6](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/04/tip-trick-integrating-asp-net-security-with-classic-asp-and-non-asp-net-urls.aspx)